# How to optimize images for printed documents

Tags: image, printing

I have some images which I saved as PNG, with resolution set to 300 DPI when exporting the images with Gimp. In the PDF generated with pdflatex, the quality is good.
Unfortunately, on paper the situation changes (80g paper).

Mainly two issues:

- many details get lost
- some colours change (e.g. bright green becomes dark green).

How can I preprocess the images to get similar results on paper like on screen?

[image: Image as given to pdflatex]

[image: Image as printed on paper]

Comment: It's most likely an issue with the colour profile. I would run `exiftool YOURIMAGE.PNG` on what you produce with GIMP and see if there is an ICC profile. If so, `pdflatex` appears to have respected it, so the issue is with whatever you used to go from PNG to paper... but you didn't say what you used for that part.

Comment: The issue disappeared when I send the PDF to a real printing service. They have printers which create exactly the same quality than on the PDF. Dont know how that machines do it, but I am happy :)